# How do you explain the associativity of the bind operator in this haskell expression?

Tags: haskell, monads

Without any parentheses :

```
Prelude> [1,2] >>= \n -> ['a', 'b'] >>= \ch -> return (n, ch)
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]
```

Parentheses assuming left associativity:

```
Prelude> ([1,2] >>= \n -> ['a', 'b']) >>= \ch -> return (n, ch)
<interactive>:22:49: Not in scope: `n'
```

Parentheses assuming right associativity:

```
Prelude> [1,2] >>= (\n -> ['a', 'b'] >>= \ch -> return (n, ch))
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]
```

Isn't `>>=` left associative? When no parentheses are present, why does GHCi evaluate the expression as if `>>=` is right associative?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, `>>=` is left associative. However, lambdas extend *as far as possible*. So the presence of the `\n ->` means that the only correct way to parse the expression is as

```
[1,2] >>= (\n -> ['a', 'b'] >>= \ch -> return (n, ch))
```

Note that your "left associativity" form

```
([1,2] >>= \n -> ['a', 'b']) >>= \ch -> return (n, ch)
```

isn't even scope-correct. The `n` in the final `return` is out of scope.

Comment: lambdas extend as far as possible. Failed to see it. Thanks !